# Background gradient se repetindo

Tags: html, css

estou montando um site para mim, e já defini as estruturas do site *(header, section, aside, footer)*.

No entanto, estou querendo colocar um plano de fundo gradiente no site inteiro.
Então eu apliquei no css:

**body {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.87), rgba(0,0,0,1));
}**

Quando salvo e vejo o site, aplicou o gradiente no site inteiro, porém o degradê começa e termina em cada limite das estruturas, fica um degradê pra header, um outro pra section, um outro pro footer, etc...

E não é isso que eu quero, eu quero o mesmo gradient para o site inteiro.
Alguém sabe o que há de errado, ou o que eu preciso colocar?

Comment: Não era pra acontecer isso não. Só daria pra saber o que está acontecendo de víssemos o código todo. Pode estar acontecendo algum conflito no CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o código abaixo resulte a saída esperada:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1))) fixed;
```

Comment: Opa, não entendi nada deste código, mas funcionou kkk
Muito obrigado! 
Deixou até um efeito legal kk

Answer (score 1):

CSS é um pouco frustrante. Mas, vou lhe ensinar da forma correta como resolver esse problema.
Isso acontece porquê você não determinou uma **largura e altura** para o seu documento.
**Para isso, use o código abaixo:**

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, red, black);
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a propriedade no-repeat para que o background não se repita:

```
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Caso tenha mais dúvidas, recomendo o site: http://maujor.com/tutorial/propriedade-css-para-estilizacao-de-background.php

Comment: Não funcionou :(
Continua repetindo na section, footer, etc..

Answer (score -2):

usa "fixed" antes do ";"

Exemplo:
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, ..., ...) fixed;